# vim-ipython cannot send to ipython in osx10.9 : "E21: Cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off"

Tags: vim, ipython, osx-mavericks

New vimmer here.  I'm trying to get vim-ipython up and running but I can't send commands to the ipython console.  I've tried setting all buffers to modifiable, every tip in the vim-ipython, etc.  I can't find any topics that have had this problem.  I suspect that it may have to do with some undo setting I goofed but I can't find anything that may be the culprit.  Including my .vimrc for your perusal.

vim error on trying to send simple command ("a=1") to iPython qtconsole:

```
In[6]: In[]: %run -i '/Users/jsb/test.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 444, in f_with_update
  File "<string>", line 395, in update_subchannel_msgs
vim.error: cannot save undo information
Error detected while processing :
E21: Cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off
```

.vimrm profile:

```
"pathogen
runtime bundle/vim-pathogen/autoload/pathogen.vim
execute pathogen#infect()

syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
"use pathogen to easily modify runtime path to include all plugins under
call pathogen#helptags()
call pathogen#incubate()

colorscheme morning

set clipboard+=unnamed

set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $* "grepping abiity, whatever this means

" hides buffers instead of closing them, so don't need to save before moving to other file
"set hidden

"set nowrap        " don't wrap lines
set tabstop=2     " a tab is four spaces
"set backspace=indent,eol,start
                  " allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
set autoindent    " always set autoindenting on
set copyindent    " copy the previous indentation on autoindenting
set number        " always show line numbers
set shiftwidth=2  " number of spaces to use for autoindenting
set shiftround    " use multiple of shiftwidth when indenting with '<' and '>'
set showmatch     " set show matching parenthesis
set ignorecase    " ignore case when searching
set smartcase     " ignore case if search pattern is all lowercase,
                  "    case-sensitive otherwise
set smarttab      " insert tabs on the start of a line according to
                  "    shiftwidth, not tabstop
set hlsearch      " highlight search terms
set incsearch     " show search matches as you type

set history=1000         " remember more commands and search history
"set undolevels=1000      " use many muchos levels of undo
"set wildignore=*.swp,*.bak,*.pyc,*.class
set title                " change the terminal's title
set visualbell           " don't beep
set noerrorbells         " don't beep
"set updatetime=1000 

"set nobackup "all backing up will be gitted thank you very much
"set noswapfile "no recovery after crashing.  just save you shit duder

" stuff for tex
" REQUIRED. This makes vim invoke Latex-Suite when you open a tex file.
filetype plugin on

" IMPORTANT: win32 users will need to have 'shellslash' set so that latex
" can be called correctly.
"set shellslash

" IMPORTANT: grep will sometimes skip displaying the file name if you
" search in a singe file. This will confuse Latex-Suite. Set your grep
" program to always generate a file-name.
set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*

" OPTIONAL: This enables automatic indentation as you type.
filetype indent on

" OPTIONAL: Starting with Vim 7, the filetype of empty .tex files defaults to
" 'plaintex' instead of 'tex', which results in vim-latex not being loaded.
" The following changes the default filetype back to 'tex':

let g:tex_flavor='latex'
let g:livepreview_previewer = 'open -a Skim'
let g:Tex_TreatMacViewerAsUNIX = 1
let g:Tex_ExecuteUNIXViewerInForeground = 1
let g:Tex_ViewRule_ps = 'open -a Skim'
let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = 'open -a /Applications/Skim.app'
let g:Tex_ViewRule_dvi = 'open -a /Applications/texniscope.app'
autocmd FileType tex call Tex_SetTeXCompilerTarget('View','pdf')
```

vim bundles:
nerdtree
rainbow_parentheses
vim-colorschemes
vim-opython
vim-latex
vim-pathogen
vim-sensible

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error you can make it modifiable by the following command

```
:set modifiable
```

Comment: tried already.  doesn't respond.  even hit it with a hammer and set all buffers to always modifiable by default and no good.
any other ideas?